# bash script that would allow automated capture of download count for books

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that would allow automated capture of download count for books from the Project Gutenberg Books Library.

For example, if a user passes the BookId of 12, you should:

Create a directory with the name of 12.

Create or append a file called Through_the_Looking-Glass

Add a new line to the file that looks similar to the one below:

2023-10-26:4625

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if Book IDs are provided as arguments
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <BookId1> [<BookId2> <BookId3> ...]"
    exit 1
fi

# Base URL for Gutendex API
BASE_URL="http://gutendex.com/books/?ids="

# Get today's date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

# Loop through each provided Book ID and process them
for bookId in "$@"; do
    # Call the Gutendex API with the provided Book ID(s)
    response=$(curl -s "$BASE_URL$bookId")

    # Extract download count from the JSON response using jq
    downloadCount=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.[].download_count')

    # Create directory if it doesn't exist
    if [ ! -d "$bookId" ]; then
        mkdir "$bookId"
    fi

    # Extract book title from the JSON response using jq and replace spaces with underscores
    bookTitle=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.[].title' | tr ' ' '_')

    # Create or append to a file with today's date and download count
    echo "$TODAY:$downloadCount" >> "$bookId/$bookTitle"

    echo "Download count for Book ID $bookId has been recorded in $bookId/$bookTitle"
done
```

The result I get:

```
./Quiz_Review.sh 12 1 14
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "download_count"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "title"
./Quiz_Review.sh: line 32: 12/: Is a directory
Download count for Book ID 12 has been recorded in 12/
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "download_count"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "title"
./Quiz_Review.sh: line 32: 1/: Is a directory
Download count for Book ID 1 has been recorded in 1/
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "download_count"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "title"
./Quiz_Review.sh: line 32: 14/: Is a directory
Download count for Book ID 14 has been recorded in 14/
```

Comment: To better isolate the issue, use xtrace mode (`bash -x yourscript`) to see what commands your script is running and thus better isolate _exactly_ where it first goes wrong so you can focus your question on that narrow, specific problem.

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. (The parts about a literal debugger aren't applicable to Bash scripts, but for that you can use Charles Duffy's suggestion above.)

Comment: (it looks like the returned JSON isn't in the form your jq script expects, but we need to know what form the JSON actually _is_ in before we can debug that; the xtrace logs will show everything needed).

Comment: Also, the script desperately needs some error handling. If the title and/or download count cannot be extracted, it shouldn't blindly try to record the non-data.

Comment: All above are true, but still a much better than average `bash` question. Keep posting! Also, two other good resources for bash script debugging 1) https://shellcheck.net (be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or similar) as first line 1a) please post shellcheck corrected code ... 2) [bash info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) , especially the section "How to turn a bad script into a good question". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A brief examination and manual parse of your specific example:

```
$: curl -s http://gutendex.com/books/?ids=12 | jq -r '.results[0].download_count'
4927
```

Using that structure, a quick reimplementation:

```
$: cat tst
#!/bin/bash

use="
  Use: $0 {BookId1} [ BookId2 [..BookIdN] ]
"
(($#)) || { echo "$use" >&2; exit 1; }                # called w/no args, exit w/instructions

base_url="http://gutendex.com/books/?ids="            # Base URL for Gutendex API
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)                               # Get today's date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
data=$(mktemp)                                        # Create a tempfile to hold any downloaded JSON
filter='.results[0].download_count,.results[0].title' # the filter for all books

for bookId in "$@"; do                                              # Loop through each provided Book ID and process them
    case $bookId in *[^0-9]*)                                       # check for nonnumeric bookId
    echo "Invalid bookId '$bookId'";                 continue;;     # skip when nonnumeric
    esac
    if [[ -d "$bookId" ]] && prev=$(grep -H "^$today:" "$bookId"/*) # check for existing entry
    then echo "Already done: $prev";                 continue       # notify and skip if found
    fi
    curl -s "$base_url$bookId" | jq -re "$filter" > "$data"         # read the count and title
    read -r downloadCount bookTitle < <( echo $(<"$data") )         # unquoted echo pulls 2 lines to 1
    if [[ null == "$bookTitle" ]]                                   # if we failed to read the title
    then echo "Cannot process bookId '$bookId'" >&2; continue       # report and skip
    fi
    mkdir -p "$bookId"                                              # Create directory if it doesn't exist
    bookTitle="${bookTitle// /_}"                                   # Replace spaces with underscores
    echo "$today:$downloadCount" >> "$bookId/$bookTitle"            # Create/append to file with date and download count
    echo "Download count for Book ID $bookId has been recorded in $bookId/$bookTitle"
done
rm $data
```

I added some basic input validation (which might not be right, making some guesses.)

Testing it:

```
$: ./tst 12 foo 15 000 99 9999
Download count for Book ID 12 has been recorded in 12/Through_the_Looking-Glass
Invalid bookId 'foo'
Download count for Book ID 15 has been recorded in 15/Moby-Dick;_or,_The_Whale
Cannot process bookId '000'
Download count for Book ID 99 has been recorded in 99/Collected_Articles_of_Frederick_Douglass
Download count for Book ID 9999 has been recorded in 9999/Harriet,_the_Moses_of_Her_People

$: ./tst 777 bogus 12
Download count for Book ID 777 has been recorded in 777/The_Mastery_of_the_Air
Invalid bookId 'bogus'
Already done: 12/Through_the_Looking-Glass:2023-11-02:4927

$: grep . */*
12/Through_the_Looking-Glass:2023-11-02:4927
15/Moby-Dick;_or,_The_Whale:2023-11-02:2311
777/The_Mastery_of_the_Air:2023-11-02:28
9999/Harriet,_the_Moses_of_Her_People:2023-11-02:62
99/Collected_Articles_of_Frederick_Douglass:2023-11-02:151
```

Always look at your data, and make sure you understand what your tools are doing as much as possible.

(and don't use all caps for vars.)

## edits

You only use two values, so I explicitly filter the `curl` for just those.

`jq` can return both at once rather than reading through the data twice, but it returns them on separate lines. I still save to a temp file, and used an unquoted `echo` to pull them back onto a single line of output for the `read` with an implicit file content dump using `$(<...)`.

This sort of hackery doesn't really gain us a lot, but does demonstrate some tricks, so it seemed worthwhile here.